# how to add sliding drawer controller in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a button when user Click on that button the slider is open to the half of screen only slider has three button add,update and delete.when user press on this button slider has been closed how to do it thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to demonstrate this:

[Android Sliding Drawer Demo](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/)